# C# JavaScriptSerializer - how to serialize as base type?

Tags: c#, javascriptserializer

I have a problem serializing with JavaScriptSerializer.
For example, I have a base class

```
public class MyBaseClass{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a derived class

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass {
    public string Patronymic { get; set; }
}
```

How can I serialize an instance of MyDerivedClass as MyBaseClass?
In case I don't want resulting JSON to contain Patronymic property?
Is it possible?

Comment: How about extracting just the required properties into an anonymous type instance and passing that to `Serialize`?

Comment: @Asad And what if I(or someone else) add some properties to one of these classes later? I' m looking for a common approach, to keep code clean.

Comment: Another alternative is to use a more customizable serializer, such as [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Should be `public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is possible to do pretty generic, with a little help of extension methods. Add this class to your project:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    //Takes one object and return a new object with type T
    public static T ToType<T>(this object value) where T : new()
    {
        var newValue = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        SetProperties(value, newValue);
        return newValue;
    }

    //Sets all properties with same name, from one source to target
    private static void SetProperties(object source, object target)
    {
        var targetType = target.GetType();
        var targetProperties = targetType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in source.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (targetProperties.Any(p => p.Name == prop.Name))
            {
                var propGetter = prop.GetGetMethod();
                var propSetter = targetType.GetProperty(prop.Name).GetSetMethod();
                var valueToSet = propGetter.Invoke(source, null);
                propSetter.Invoke(target, new[] { valueToSet });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use this code to serialize `MyDerivedClass` as `MyBaseClass`

```
var myDerivedObj = new MyDerivedClass { Id = 1, Name = "Test", Patronymic = "Patronymic" };
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var myDerivedString = serializer.Serialize(myDerivedObj);
var myBaseObj = myDerivedObj.ToType<MyBaseClass>(); //Converting
var myBaseString = serializer.Serialize(myBaseObj); //This string is what you want
```